# Running Animation sample app (for Sceneform) on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to run the [Animation sample app](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/animation) on my Android Emulator:

- Pixel 2 API 27 Oreo
- Android 8.1 x86

but the app keeps crashing.

Below are my logcat warnings: (I only copied the lines in orange)

> E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008a30
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknown param 0x00008a30 E/native:
>   online_calibration_manager.cc:47 OnlineCalibrationManager: Could not
>   open
>   /data/user/0/com.google.ar.sceneform.samples.animation/cache/arcore-online-recalibration
>   for reading. E/NdkImageReader: AImageReader_getWindow E/native:
>   session.cc:1397 Invalid ray produced by view data! A/libc: Fatal
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 128, fault addr 0x0 in tid 6227
>   (mples.animation), pid 6227 (mples.animation)

I can run hello_ar_java sample on the emulator, so I guess the configurations of the emulator are correct?

Comment: Can you check that your development environment has the minimum required configuration to run AR Core API ? You can check the link https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/emulator

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA yes it meets the requirements